Supabase Permission Denied Error on Insertion Using Next.js Server Actions
I'm trying to insert data into a Supabase table using a Next.js server action, but I'm encountering the following error:
Error: Failed to create log pool: permission denied for schema public
Here is my setup:
Server Action:
'use server';

import { createClient } from "@/utils/supabase/server";
import { revalidatePath } from 'next/cache';

export async function createLogPool(data: FormData) {
  const name = data.get('name') as string | null;
  const description = data.get('description') as string | null;
  const orgId = data.get('organization') as string | null;
  const supabase = createClient();

  if (!name || !description || !orgId) {
    throw new Error('All fields are required');
  }

  const { error } = await supabase.from('LogPool').insert({
    name,
    description,
    orgId: orgId
  });

  if (error) {
    console.error('Supabase Error:', error);
    throw new Error(`Failed to create log pool: ${error.message}`);
  }

  revalidatePath('/settings');
}

Modal Form (Client-Side):
"use client";

import { DialogContent, DialogHeader, DialogTitle, DialogDescription } from "@/components/ui/dialog";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Label } from "@/components/ui/label";
import { createLogPool } from "../actions"; 

export default function NewPoolModal() {
  return (
    <DialogContent>
      <DialogHeader>
        <DialogTitle>New Pool</DialogTitle>
        <DialogDescription>Create a new log pool</DialogDescription>
      </DialogHeader>
      <form action={createLogPool} className="space-y-4">
        <div>
          <Label htmlFor="name">Name</Label>
          <Input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter pool name" required />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Label htmlFor="description">Description</Label>
          <Input id="description" name="description" placeholder="Enter pool description" required />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Label htmlFor="organization">Organization</Label>
          <Input id="organization" name="organization" value="688202df-6e7d-41a4-bd3c-a304038e4816" readOnly />
        </div>
        <Button type="submit" className="w-full mt-4 bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-700">Create Pool</Button>
      </form>
    </DialogContent>
  );
}

To resolve the permission issue, I tried enabling Row-Level Security (RLS) and added a policy:
create policy "Allow insert access" on public."LogPool" for insert with check ( true );
--also 
npx prisma migrate deploy

However, I'm still getting the "permission denied for schema public" error.
I believe there might be something wrong with either the RLS configuration or the policy setup. Any advice on how to correctly set permissions for inserts would be greatly appreciated!
PS : I've forgot to join Policies about table but i just joined it

If you are using Prisma you have likely wiped your database permissions. Check the troubleshooting section of this page https://supabase.com/partners/integrations/prisma
